# How can I Show the difference between values of two columns of devexpress gridview into anothere column

Tags: javascript, c#, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridview in which there is a column containing textbox. Users will input integer values into the textbox. I want to show the differences between the given values(textboxes) and values of a column of the gridview into another column of the gridview. Client side is preferable. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can easily do this using JavaScript. assign client instance id to you edit control e.g. text box in current cell and text box of another cell.. then you can get the value of these control..

Answer (score 0):

Follow these reference links to find solution for your desired functionality:
[ASPxGridView - How to get a value of ASPxTextBox placed in DataItemTemplate](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q438457)
[ASPxGridView - How to set value for ASPxTextBox on client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q519827)
[ASPxGridView - How to perform client-side validation of Edit Form controls placed in ASPxPageControl](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q385931)
[ASPxGridView - Get value of a textbox in Edit Form on the client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T158592)

> Set your [ASPxTextBox.ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEditBase_ClientInstanceNametopic) property of TextBox to
> access it client side. After this, you can use the client-side
> ASPxClientTextBox.SetText or ASPxClientTextBox.GetText method to set a
> value to the textbox.

May be this example specific to your requirement:
[ASPxGridView - How to calculate column values on the client side via editors inside DataItemTemplate](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3929)

Hope this help.